# Setting Initial Value to Picker MVVM Xamarin Sets ObservableCollection to NULL

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to set the initalvalue of a picker in a a list view. However, when I have tried nothing is set and the underlying source is set to null. The picker is populated with a list of strings and displays correctly. I'm tyring to set the intial value to IngredientName which is also a string.

in my getData function you can watch each time the _downloadedRecipeIngredients loop is run the IngredientName field is overwritten with NULL.

Please help

The picker in question is named 'pickerIngredientancestor'

XAML

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        
        <ListView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding downloadedRecipeIngredients}">  <!--SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"-->
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Picker x:Name="pickerIngredientancestor" HorizontalOptions = "StartAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding listIngredients, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModel:testPageViewModel}}}" SelectedItem="{Binding IngredientName}" WidthRequest="100"/>
                            <Entry Text="{Binding Comments}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                            <Label Text="Clickable Label" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.btnPress, Source={x:Reference Page}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

VIEW MODEL

```
public class testPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<clRecipeIngredient> _downloadedRecipeIngredients = new ObservableCollection<clRecipeIngredient>();
    public ObservableCollection<clRecipeIngredient> downloadedRecipeIngredients
    { 
        get { return _downloadedRecipeIngredients; } 
        set 
        {
            _downloadedRecipeIngredients = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        } 
    }

    ObservableCollection<string> _listIngredients = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> listIngredients { get { return _listIngredients; } }

    private clRecipeDataBase recipeDataBase;

    public testPageViewModel()
    {
        recipeDataBase = new clRecipeDataBase();

        getData();
    }

    async void getData()
    {
        //PICKER INGREDIENT DATA
        clIngredient[] tmp = await recipeDataBase.getIngredientData();
        //picker.ItemsSource = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Length; i++)
        {
            _listIngredients.Add(tmp[i].IngredientName);
        }

        clRecipeIngredient[] arr = await recipeDataBase.getRecipeIngredientsDataByRecipeID(310); //HARDCODED TO CRISPY PIZZA RECIPE
        clRecipeIngredient tmp1;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            _downloadedRecipeIngredients.Add(arr[i]);
        }


    }
```

---

Initial Values for the arrays:

This is some of the data for listIngredients. These strings are used to populate the possible choices for the picker.

[image]

This is how the data is initially downloaded for RecipeIngredients
[image]

However, as this array is stored into the ObservableCollection the IngredientName is changed to NULL.

[image]

Comment: I test the code you provided. How do you set the property of `IngredientName` and what is the value? When i make a model `downloadedRecipeIngredients` include `listIngredients` and `IngredientName`, it works well. Please check the `downloadedRecipeIngredients`. Do this include the `IngredientName` correctly?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Thanks for the help. I added additional information of what is contained in those variables above. All of these are downloaded form a SQL server through a REST call.

Comment: changing to a regular array seems to eliminate the NULL issue however the picker isn't setting to the binding. I know the binding is correct as I have it duplicated in the XAML now with:

        <Entry VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Text="{Binding IngredientName}"/>
and this entry displays the IngredientName string as expected. However the Picker doesn't update to the seleecteditem as expected. UGUGHGHGHGHGH

Comment: It seems there is something wrong when you add the data into `ObservableCollection`. Have you try to debug when you foreach the list you downloaded and then add it into collection step by step? When you add it, do you get the correct value and add the correct value?